# How to set the width of each header cell in a table (with fixed header) to be the same to the biggest in its column, and make the browser respect it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the infamous table:

[image]

My boss wants me, at this time of the year, to make the header of the table fixed, so the user can scroll down the table and continue reading the header. I want to preserve the original precomputed dimensions of the table, I mean, the width that every column has at the moment of its creation (widths aren't established by CSS) and then, adapt the header so its columns match the columns of the body. Following some of the answers I found in Stackoverflow, I started making the header and the body of the table `display: block`. And after that, I wrote this:

```
function setTableHeadDimensions() {
    var $taskTable = $('.tablaTareas_PEMVISUALIZA'),
        $firstRow = $taskTable.find('tbody > tr:first-child'),
        $firstRowTds = $firstRow.find('td'),
        $firstRowHead = $taskTable.find('thead > tr:first-child'),
        $secondRowHead = $taskTable.find('thead > tr:eq(1)'),
        $firstRowHeadThs = $firstRowHead.find('th'),
        $secondRowHeadThs = $secondRowHead.find('th'),
        i = 0,
        cells = [];

    //We prepare CSS, so we can specify width.
    $taskTable
        .css('table-layout', 'fixed')
        .find('td, th').each(function () {
            var $tdh = $(this);
            $tdh.css('box-sizing', 'border-box');
            $tdh.css('overflow', 'hidden');
        });

    //Cells of the first row of the table head.
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cells.push($($firstRowHeadThs[i]));
    }

    //Cells of the second row of the table head.
    for (i = 0; i < $secondRowHeadThs.length; i++) {
        cells.push($($secondRowHeadThs[i]));
    }

    //Rest of the cells for the first row.
    for (i = 5; i < $firstRowHeadThs.length; i++) {
        cells.push($($firstRowHeadThs[i]));
    }

    //Try to set the width of the current column's header cell
    //to the biggest cell width in the column.
    for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var maxWidth = 0;

        $taskTable.find('td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').each(function () {
            var $el = $(this);
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $el.width());
        });

        cells[i].width(maxWidth);
    }
}
```

But, as you can see in the picture, the browser doesn't want to cooperate. What's more, it establishes the width of the cell, but to a number that doesn't match the width of it's corresponding column:

[image]

What's more, it doesn't match the width of the row it should match:

[image]

So I have two questions:

1. Why does the browser behave in the way it does?
2. How can I solve this problem in a way compatible with IE8? (no fancy CSS3 solution, please)

Here's a codepen with the example cut down to the minimum necessary: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/PolarKuma/pen/mONWPd)

Comment: Cell widths have always behaved more as hints than as absolute rules. If cell content needs more room, the cell will grow bigger than the specified width. If other cells need more room, then the cell will shrink below the specified width if it has unused space. In this case the cells top-right seem to want a lot of room. Make them short or empty, as an experiment, and go from there.

Comment: as soon as you break the display of a table, or split it into many tables the layout is broken and cols from each parts comes appart. there is a way with table-layout:fixed and setting width for each cols/cells, or use javascript. There's many similar question here.

Comment: @GCyrillus I already tested what you propose without results. Yes, I know there are many similar questions here but none of them seems to work for me. What really bothers me is the way the browser seems to deceive me. I'm telling it "hey, browser, all these cells have this width" but then it answers me "so what..." I logged to the console the widths returned by ´$el.width()´, what's interesting is that they don't coincide with the widths of their respective cells, as you can see in the screenshots. The question is **why**.

Comment: to fixe width on table/table-cells, you need also to use table-layout:fixed; else width will adjust no matter width set in css :( **edit** oups, just saw you did. can you set up a working snippet(or fiddle/codepen ? i found an hold dabblet i used to answer something similar afew years ago http://dabblet.com/gist/5648624 if that gives an hint

Comment: @GCyrillus Here you have [link](https://codepen.io/PolarKuma/pen/mONWPd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. In reality, there were two problems:

The first one is that `jQuery.width()` returns only the width of the content of the cell, without padding and margin (even if you specify `border-sizing: border-box`). I found more natural to use `jQuery.css('width')` and then take borders and padding into account in my calculations, without specifying `border-sizing: border-box` because retrieving the width with `border-sizing: border-box` and then setting it in another element with the idea of matching both widths can be error prone (I had problems with it).

The second one is if you use `rowspan` in the header of the table. In that case, you have to establish the width of the rows envolved doing the proper calculations, not only one of them hopping that the rest of the rows will adapt.

Here's the codepen with the solution: http://codepen.io/PolarKuma/pen/BQXMbO